# Can there exist a function $f$ for which $\Delta f(x)$ is not of the form $\Delta x(...)$ where $(...)$ is some expression?

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification

Let us assume that $f$ is a function. Let $\Delta x$ denote the change in $x$ and $\Delta f(x)$ denote the corresponding change in $f(x)$. So, $\Delta  f(x) = f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)$.

Now, for most of the functions that I am familiar with, $\Delta f(x)$ is of the form $\Delta x(...)$, where $(...)$ represents some expression and none of its terms have $\Delta x$ in their denominator when completely simplified. For example, if $f(x) = x^2$, then $\Delta f(x) = 2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 = \Delta x(\Delta x + 2x)$.

**Can there exist a function $f$, for which $\Delta f(x)$ is not of this form?** If yes, how would we differentiate it?

I have thought of a method which has led me to conclude that such a function does not exist. I assumed that for a function $f_2$, $\Delta f_2(x)$ is not of the form $\Delta x (..)$. I assumed that for such a function, $\Delta f_2(x)$ can be written as $k + \Delta x(...)$. But, if we assume that $\Delta x = 0$, then $\Delta f_2(x) = f_2(x + \Delta x) - f_2(x) = f_2(x) - f_2(x) = 0$ but using $\Delta f_2(x) = k + \Delta x(...)$, we get $\Delta f_2(x) = k + 0(...) = k$.

This means that $k = 0$ and hence, for some function $f$, $\Delta f(x)$ is always of the form $\Delta x(...)$.

But I am extremely doubtful about this and I would like to verify it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$? In this case $\Delta f(x) =-\Delta x(\frac{1}{x(x+\Delta x)})$ As of now I don't see how you remove that $\Delta x$ from the denominator.

Comment: @JnPS Good example...

Comment: Trigonometric functions also in general won't have even a $\Delta x$ in their expression for $\Delta f(x)$, no? The angle addition identities never have pull out the angle I believe, It's pretty late where I am so I'm not confident enough to type up an answer.

Comment: @JnPS This confuses me about differentiation of some functions but I'm not able to come up with right words to phrase the confusion